# How to search with firstname and last name in - Mysql

Tags: mysql, search

Consider I am having tow fields in my table

```
field_profile_first_name_value      field_profile_last_name_value

Victor                              Brecher
Abhi                                Jass             

select field_profile_first_name_value, field_profile_last_name_value 
from content_type_profile where field_profile_first_name_value LIKE '%Victor Bre%' OR 
field_profile_last_name_value LIKE '%Victor Bre%'
```

I am having a auto complete text box.

**When i enter the keyword as victor it will fetch the result. But if i give the first name and last name in the same time it will not produce the result.**

**That is if i give the keyword as Victor Brecher it will not produce the result.**

How can i make to get the result if i enter first name and last name ?

How can i make it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try :

```
select * from contracts 
where lower(concat_ws(' ', field_profile_first_name_value, field_profile_last_name_value)) 
like lower('%Victor Bre%')
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, even you don't need to use lower too. just use it simply.

```
select * from contracts where concat_ws(' ', field_profile_first_name_value,field_profile_last_name_value)
like '%Victor Bre%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of soundex.

```
select * from contracts where SOUNDEX(concat_ws(' ', field_profile_first_name_value,field_profile_last_name_value)) =  SOUNDEX('Victor Bre');
```

Comment: If no results returned using like '%name%' then SOUNDEX search would return results that are similar sounding in case name misspelling.

Comment: This is my bad -- I was reviewing "new contributions" and saw this as a question, not an answer -- it's definitely a contribution to the problem, and I will reverse my downvote to an upvote if the answer is edited so I can reverse.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this code, so the search works also if the search input is the lastname before the name

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
  contracts
WHERE
   CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) LIKE 'Victor Bre%'
OR CONCAT(lastname, ' ', firstname)) LIKE 'Victor Bre%';
```

Moreover, I tested this sql code with and without LOWER(), in mysql 5.7+ the search already do that.